# MS Access 2003 Refresh Linked ODBC Tables in VBA Causes Bloat

Tags: vba, ms-access

Using the following code, it is bloating the database size when refreshing the linked ODBC table connections. As such, the user will never be be able to finish the process completely without closing and re-opening the database for it to compact. The connections are linked from SQL and there are 13 linked tables in the database. The code resets the connection 4 times.

```
   Dim dbs As DAO.Database   
   Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef  
   Dim rs As DAO.Recordset  
   Dim strSite As String  

   Set dbs = CurrentDb  
   Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("tblSites")  

   'Run query against Default Site to create table  
   DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qryWarranty01") 'creates tblWarranty  

   'Loop through Site 2, Site 3 & Site 4 and append data to table  
    With rs  
        .MoveFirst  
        Do While .EOF = False  
        strSite = rs.Fields("Site")   
            For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs  
                If Len(tdf.Connect) > 0 Then  
                tdf.Connect = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=ServerName;DATABASE=" & strSite & ";UID=Username; PWD=Password;"  
                tdf.RefreshLink  
                End If  
            Next  
            DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryWarranty02"  'appends to tblWarranty  
        .MoveNext  
        Loop  
End With   
rs.Close  

'Reset tables to be linked to Default Site
For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs  
If Len(tdf.Connect) > 0 Then  
    tdf.Connect = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=ServerName;DATABASE=Site1;UID=Username; PWD=Password;"  
    tdf.RefreshLink  
End If  
Next
```

I've searched and searched for a resolution beyond Compacting and Repair. Can someone explain to me why the bloat is happening in this code and so fast? Is there another way to accomplish what I am needing to do?

I appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Cara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some possibilities:

- Ignore the bloat. Is it so extreme? What is so bad about Repair&Compact?
- Only change `.Connect` and `RefreshLink` the tables that are used in `qryWarranty02`, not all 11 tables.
- Create a SQL Server view from `qryWarranty02`, link that view. Now you only have to switch one TableDef.
- Use a Pass-Through query instead of the linked view. I don't think changing the .Connect of a PT query causes the same bloat as for a table.
- Have 4 Pass-Through queries with fixed connect strings for the 4 databases, and loop through them. No switching anymore (but redundancy in the queries).

Comment: The bloat was so extreme that all the processes that needed to be completed could not without closing in the middle of it. Creating/using Pass-Through queries solved this issue perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That's normal and known (mis)behaviour.

You have no other options than either ignore the bloat (which you safely can do) or perform a compact afterwards.